# Unable to publishtomavenlocal due to components.java

Tags: gradle

Unable to publish to maven local with gradle 7.3.3.

project's `build.gradle`:

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

def gitBranch() {
    def branch = ""
    def proc = "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD".execute()
    proc.in.eachLine { line -> branch = line }
    proc.err.eachLine { line -> println line }
    proc.waitFor()
    branch
}

group = 'my.project'
version = gitBranch()

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

subprojects {
    project.version = gitBranch()
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs "../ZKM"
        }
    }

    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
                artifactId = jar.archiveBaseName
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

This returns the error:

> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'my-project'.
> Could not get unknown property 'java' for SoftwareComponentInternal set of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apply the `java` plugin only to the root project (“my-project”) of the build. The subprojects don’t seem to apply the plugin, hence `components.java` is unknown in their build configurations.

You can fix this by simply adding `apply plugin: 'java'` somewhere near the beginning of your `subprojects { … }` block.

Comment: Do we really need to add `from components.java`? Why is its use exactly? I didn't add it and it is still working for me. The only thing I added is :


plugins {
  ..
  id 'maven-publish'
}


publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            // from components.java
        }
    }
}

Comment: `from components.java` defines what to publish. `components.java` is the [`SoftwareComponent`](https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/component/SoftwareComponent.html) defined by the Java Plugin, i.e., the `from components.java` means to publish this component. If you comment this line, then your build may not fail anymore (if it did before like for the OP of the question), however, I wonder if the build will still publish the right things (unless you configure the publication elsewhere).